# Choosing error for a linear regression model when simulating data for a bayesian sample size determination

Tags: bayesian, sample-size, simulation, error

**Background:** I am writing a grant and trying to get a sample size estimate for a Bayesian linear regression. I am trying to link a brain measure to a change in a behavioral measure. So the model is really simple: Y ~ bX + e, where Y is change and X is the brain measure.

**Question 1:** Based on previous research I know the means and sd's of both Y & X. Can I use these values to choose a realistic e for simulations, or at least a reasonable lower bound? Or is there a better way to go about this?

**Question 2:** I plan to fit a Bayesian linear regression to the data with varying b. I'll then choose the b where  89% credibility interval does not cross 0 as the minimum detectable association with a given N. Does this make sense?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For Question (1):

Idea: Repeat your prior analysis but first standardize all the Ys and Xs (so, for example, new X' = (X - Mean(x))/Sigma(x).

The set of residues may be a sample of possible error terms for a new set of Beta also modeled on standardized data.

Still thinking about an answer to Question (2).

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I must clarify the question 1 a bit. I don't have the data. I only know the variance of the variables from previous literature.